# C++ File IO with Strings and Float

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm learning some file io in C++. I've created a `class person` and two functions `write` and `read`.

It `write` correctly into the file but when I want to `read` and initialize `person` objects with `read` it will only work in the first run.

I think it has to do with the `float age` variable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>  

using namespace std;

class person{
public:
    person();
    person(string, string, float);

    string getName();
    string getAddress();
    float  getAge();

    void setName(string);
    void setAddress(string);
    void setAge(float);

    ~person();

private:    
    string name, address;
    float age;    
};

person::person(){
    //NOTHING TO DO.
}

person::person(string NAME, string ADD, float AGE) 
: name(NAME), address(ADD), age(AGE){
    //NOTHING TO DO.
}

string person::getName(){
    return name;
}
string person::getAddress(){
    return address;
}
float person::getAge(){
    return age;
}

void person::setName(string NAME){
    name = NAME;
}
void person::setAddress(string ADD){
    address = ADD;
}
void person::setAge(float AGE){
    age = AGE;
}

void write(person* pA[], int sz){
    ofstream myfile("people.txt", ios::trunc);
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
        myfile << pA[i]->getName()    << endl
                << pA[i]->getAddress() << endl
                 << fixed << setprecision(2)
                  << pA[i]->getAge()    << endl;
    }     
}
person* read(ifstream & myfile){
    person* p = new person();
    string name, address;
    float age;

    getline(myfile, name);
    getline(myfile, address);
    myfile >> age;

    p->setName(name);
    p->setAddress(address);
    p->setAge(age);

    return p;
}

int main() {
    person* p0 = new person("Edward Jones", "Los Angeles", 22.2);
    person* p1 = new person("Floyd Mayweather", "Las Vegas", 26);
    person* p2 = new person("Jane Doe", "Paris", -99);

    int sz = 3; //size of array.
    person* pA[3];

    pA[0] = p0;
    pA[1] = p1;
    pA[2] = p2;

    write(pA,sz);

    person* newP0;
    person* newP1;
    person* newP2;

    ifstream myfile("people.txt");

    newP0 = read(myfile);
    newP1 = read(myfile);
    newP2 = read(myfile);

    myfile.close();

    cout 
    << newP0->getName() << endl << newP0->getAddress() << endl << newP0->getAge()
    << newP1->getName() << endl << newP1->getAddress() << endl << newP1->getAge()
    << newP2->getName() << endl << newP2->getAddress() << endl << newP2->getAge();

    return 0;
}
```

I appreciate your help, of course this looks like a code nightmare to most of you, I apologize. I know this is very basic.

Thanks!

Comment: BTW you need to delete `person`s created by `new` operator.

Comment: Yes, thanks! This is just a toy app but of course that's important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this code writes each member of `Person` as a separate line, it should read it back as lines as well.

Instead of:

```
myfile >> age;
```

Do:

```
string age_str;
getline(myfile, age_str);
std::istringstream(age_str) >> age;
```

---

In

```
person* pA[2];
pA[0] = p0;
pA[1] = p1;
pA[2] = p2;
```

`pA[2] = p2` writes past the array corrupting the stack.

Comment: Oh, I used `myfile >> age` cause I thought otherwise it wouldn't conserve the float 'format'. I will try! Also sorry about the array, I added one more person to see what happened, clearly didn't tested it.

Comment: It worked thanks! Added the deletes and adjusted the array's size to make it work. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @DanielSegura You may like to use `std::vector<Person>` to avoid manual memory management.

Comment: I will take a look into that. Again, thanks I was stuck there.